# Accessing XElement's attribute with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, xelement

I'm parsing an XElement object like this one

```
XElement teachers = new XElement("Teachers",
    new XElement("Teacher1", 
        new XAttribute("Age", 27)),
    new XElement("Teacher2",
        new XAttribute("Age", 60)),
    new XElement("Teacher3"),
        new XAttribute("Age", 50));
```

With this code:

```
IEnumerable<string> oldTeachers = from teacher in teachers.Elements()
                                        where int.Parse(teacher.Attribute("Age").Value) > 40
                                        orderby teacher.Name.ToString() ascending 
                                        select teacher.Name.ToString();
```

But i get a runtime error saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object on the where line.
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I found the problem being the XElement declaration: the right one should have been this:

```
XElement teachers = new XElement("Teachers",
    new XElement("Teacher1", 
        new XAttribute("Age", 27)),
    new XElement("Teacher2",
        new XAttribute("Age", 60)),
    new XElement("Teacher3",
        new XAttribute("Age", 50)));
```

Comment: I still would like to know where the Age of the this Teacher was being declared. Debugging didn't really helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should not establish identity through the name of an element.  The name of an element should be the name of a concept of what it represents.  By naming your elements `Teacher1`, `Teacher2`, and `Teacher3`, you're making it harder to process than it should.  If you need identity, add an attribute to your teachers.

```
var teachers = new XElement("Teachers",
    new XElement("Teacher",
        new XAttribute("Id", 1),
        new XAttribute("Age", 27)
    ),
    new XElement("Teacher",
        new XAttribute("Id", 2),
        new XAttribute("Age", 60)
    ),
    new XElement("Teacher",
        new XAttribute("Id", 3),
        new XAttribute("Age", 50)
    )
);
```

In LINQ to XML, if you needed the value of an Attribute/Element, you should cast to the appropriate type.

```
var oldTeachers =
    from teacher in teachers.Elements("Teacher")
    where (int)teacher.Attribute("Age") > 40
    orderby (int)teacher.Attribute("Id") ascending
    select "Teacher" + (int)teacher.Attribute("Id"); // or simply return the Id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always print XML constructed by your code using `XElement.ToString()`, the first code added the `Age="50"` attribute to `<Teachers>` node :

```
<Teachers Age="50">
  <Teacher1 Age="27" />
  <Teacher2 Age="60" />
  <Teacher3 />
</Teachers>
```

And the 2nd code correctly adds the attribute to the `<Teacher3>` node :

```
<Teachers>
  <Teacher1 Age="27" />
  <Teacher2 Age="60" />
  <Teacher3 Age="50" />
</Teachers>
```

Just to make it clear, I got above XMLs using this simple line :

```
Console.WriteLine(teachers);
//or more verbose :
//Console.WriteLine(teachers.ToString());
```

FYI, you can avoid such exception by casting the `XAttribute` to `int?` (but in this case, getting exception seems better to make you aware that something wrong in the `XElement` construction :

```
IEnumerable<string> oldTeachers = from teacher in teachers.Elements()
                                  where (int?)teacher.Attribute("Age") > 40
                                  orderby teacher.Name.ToString() ascending
                                  select teacher.Name.ToString();
```